# How can I dynamically update 'src' in <script src=> in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, squarespace, zoho

I an trying to grab url parameters onto a Zoho form in Squarespace for Google tracking purposes. I made a custom function to get the parameter and add it to a url. The alerts at the end are just to show that it is getting set correctly. But I am unable to add the form with the variable 'site'.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }
    var campaign = getUrlVars()["campaign"];
    var site = "https://forms.zohopublic.com/....wj7Q?campaign="+campaign;
      var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
      scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
      scriptElement.src = site;
      scriptElement.id = "ZFScript";
      document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
      alert(decodeURI(campaign));
      alert(site);
      alert(scriptElement.src);
      alert(scriptElement.type);
      alert(scriptElement.id);
</script>
```

So at the end I just need to run

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=site id="ZFScript"></script>
```

But I can not get it to write a new script with src equaling the site variable.

Comment: maybe try scriptElement.setAttribute('src',site) ? or scriptElement.src = '"' + site + '"' or something like that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only javascript, you almost got it as @Julesezaar comment, I complement it with something like this:

```
document.getElementById('ZFScript').setAttribute('src',site);
```

And you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  
I removed 'scriptElement.src = site;' and added your code after 'scriptElement.id = "ZFScript";' and the form is still not showing up, and it's not triggering anything after that line now, like the alerts.